# Why both training and testing loss decrease as I add more training data incrementally?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using Keras to develop a online learning application by using model.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch). I tried to add training data incrementally, and plot out the loss of both testing and training. The result is below,

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deXJ4.png)

It's good to see the testing loss is decreasing, but as I learned in Andrew Ng's ML class, if I have a powerful model like a DNN, the training loss is supposed to increase as I add more training data incrementally, and the testing loss is supposed to decrease. So, I am really confused. Below a screen shot of his slides.

[Andrew's slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f47fG.png)

Comment: At what point did you measure the training and testing losses?  I have little idea what your ordinal axis represents.

Comment: Not diving much into details, this idea comming up: Andrew may have plotted summed error, and you are plotting out average

Comment: What happens to accuracy of both datasets?  Does it increase also?

Comment: The ordinal axis is the training size which I increase incrementally. The losses were measured at the end of each training phase. You can see the code here if you like: https://github.com/stccenter/datadiscovery/blob/master/ranking/online_processing.py#L58

Comment: The accuracy does increase, just the opposite of the loss.

Comment: Did you find an explanation to your observation? Please can you share?

Comment: @ClaudeCOULOMBE It has been a while, but I think the key point here is that what I posted can be thought of a SGD process, which is different from what Andrew were discussing in the lecture. More specifically, Andrew measures error after overfitting the training data, however, what I did is just to update the gradient using new data (SINGLE update, not overfitting or complete training pointed out by Nilesh). I know it's tricky, but you just need to think about what really happens behind these charts. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as I learned in Andrew Ng's ML class, if I have a powerful model like a DNN, the training loss is supposed to increase as I add more training data incrementally, and the testing loss is supposed to decrease.

Yes this is true. Suppose you are using very small training data and using some powerful model to train, In such case your model is capable to remember every training sample and model settings would be very specific to train data, model knows every training sample and it's output label, so training loss will be very small. But same setting fails on test data and produces bad results, that is what we call model overfiting.

Solution to ovoid overfiting are:

- **Increase training data**: When you increase training data, your model can't remember all training data, but it will try to find some general setting that applies to majority of training data for reducing loss during training. But same general settings can also be applicable to predict on test data. So by increasing training data, training loss is increased but test loss decreases and that is what expected for Prediction.
- **Reduce model complexity**: Same applies here when you reduce model complexity, your model can't remember all training data. So training loss increases and test loss decreases.

Now come to your problem. Why this not applies to your case?.

I strongly believes that the graph you plotted is during your training phase. In neural network settings, model initial weights are set randomly so it produces very high training error on first batch and update parameter variable using backpropagation. Now when it comes to second batch model has learn somethings about training data in first batch so expected error in second batch will be little low. This goes on for each subsequent batches. The graph you produces is during model training and that is what behavior we see in training.

If you wants to test Andrew Ng's hypothesis then split your training data in 1/4, 1/2,..1. different sizes sets. Train each dataset until your training loss reducing. On final iteration results for each dataset you can observe that model with fever training samples producing lower training error and higher test error, and with increase in size of data, training errors are increasing but test errors are decreasing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying Andrew's hypothesis is not about SGD?

Comment: No it's not about SGD. It is about if you increase size of training data your train loss increases and test loss decreases after complete training.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really puzzled... I’ve learned and observed that training loss / error increases with training data size as stated in Dr Andrew Ng’s ML course.

[image]

I’ve recently experienced the same anomaly. Training loss and validation loss curves were decreasing while training data size was increasing. The code was plotting after all the training was entirely done. In fact, I’ve trained 10 different DNN models with increasing quantity of data as suggested above by Nilesh Birari.

[image]

I suspect that Dr Ng’s drawing assumes that the number of data points is already pretty large. The drawing does not show the training error curve for small training sets. Maybe in that area, for high capacity DNN both training loss and validation loss can decrease together as the training data  size increases.

That said, I’ve got the Dr Ng’s described behavior with small classical machine learning models using the same code but different data for both experiments, I just have to replace the model.
[image]

Comment: The answer, as so often in Machine Learning, is in the data. Examining my data, I've found that they were ordered, but I was sure that was not the case. So, the key point is that we should ALWAYS SHUFFLE THE DATA but keeping inputs and labels associated. Point 7 of the [37 Reasons why your Neural Network is not working](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607)